# How could I show that the set of degenerate critical points of a $C^{\infty}$ function is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R^n}$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

What would be a good idea to show( or finding a counter example) the set of degenerate critical points of a $C^{\infty}$ function $f: \mathbb{R^n}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R^n}$? Also, any insight into what this set looks like would also be appreciated.

Comment: A critical point is degenerate if and only if $\det(\nabla^2 f) = 0$, where $\nabla^2 f$ is the Hessian of $f$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $N\subset \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ be the subspace of Matrices $M$ with $\det(M) = 0$. This subspace is closed, since it is equal to $\det^{-1}(\{0\})$.
Since $f\in C^\infty$, the mappings $\nabla f,\nabla^2f$ are continuous. Hence, $(\nabla f)^{-1}(\{0_{\mathbb R^n}\})\cap (\nabla^2f)^{-1}(N)$ is closed as intersection of closed sets.

Comment: It would be nice if you'd tell me if you understood now.

Comment: How is the subspace equal to $det({0})^{-1}$?

Comment: This is exactly the definition of the preimage.. And I didn't write $det(0)^{-1}$ but $det^{-1}(\{0\})$.

Comment: I don't quite understand how the subspace is equal to a number.

Comment: It is not a number. It is a set. Look up the definition of preimage.

Comment: Wiki: "The inverse image or preimage of a particular subset S of the codomain of a function is the set of all elements of the domain that map to the members of S."

Comment: How is $det^{-1}({ 0 })$ a set?